# Получение GET-параметров в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли такое?

Comment: Возможно. Я так понимаю, что следующий вопрос: "Как?" ))

Comment: верно)))))

Answer (score 5):

Варианты есть разные, но принцип один:

```
function parseUrlQuery() {
    var data = {}
        ,   pair = false
        ,   param = false;
    if(location.search) {
        pair = (location.search.substr(1)).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < pair.length; i ++) {
            param = pair[i].split('=');
            data[param[0]] = param[1];
        }
    }
    return data;
}

console.log(parseUrlQuery());
```

Comment: функция выводит [Object] Как получить конкретный параметр?)

Comment: Если, к примеру, URI site.ru/?id=100&page=main, то:

    /* функция и */
    var allParams = parseUrlQuery();
    alert(allParams.id);
    alert(allParams.page);

Comment: А если у меня ЧПУ???

Comment: С этого начинать надо было. **location.pathname** выташит из ссылки вида "http://site.ru/param1/param2/param3/" - "**/param1/param2/param3/**". Теперь можно разбить по слешу, если надо. Вот и будут части

Comment: Плиззз. Вот вариант, как на части разбить с очисткой от лишних слешей:

    function parseUrlQuery(){
        var parts = false
        ,   path = location.pathname;
        if(path){
            parts = path.split('/').filter(function(e){return e});
        }
        return parts;
    }

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо еще раз! Выручил!

Comment: Как вариант - инлайн скрипты и бэкэндом подставляем что нужно.

    <script>
        var i = <?= $i; ?>
    </script>