# Как получить параметры url в виде объекта javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Как превратить url query string в объект javascript'a по типу:

URL

```
http://mydomain.com/?dishes=3&hot=true&cuisine=italian&tips=true
```

в объект

```
urlParams = {
 dishes:3,
 hot:true,
 cuisine:italian,
 tips=true
};
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/287469/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-get-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-javascript

Comment: не всегда срабатывает, наприм в этом случае http://localhost:9000/#/eventCenters/22001?test=234&num=423 возвращает пустой объект

Comment: правильно, потому что тут только якорь есть и ни каких параметров. Не надо пихать решетку `#` не по назначению.

Comment: да, но это yeoman на пару с grunt'ом мне прикалдовывают, и мне нужно с этим считаться, поэтому я думал об использовании window.location.href как вариант

Comment: Ну так убирайте `#/` перед разбором параметров и пользуйтесь готовым решением

Comment: я немного изменил то код, теперь он подходит так и под мой случай - if(window.location.href) {
    pair = window.location.href.split('?');
    pair = pair[1].split('&');

Answer (score 1):

```
function ofUrl(url) {
    var o = {};
    var ms = url.match(/(\w+=[^&]+)/gi);
    for(var i=0; i < ms.length; i++) { 
        var v = ms[i].split("=");
        o[v[0]] = v[1];
    }
    return o;
}
var o = ofUrl("http://mydomain.com/?dishes=3&hot=true&cuisine=italian&tips=true");
alert(o.cuisine + " " + o.tips);        // выводит "italian true"
```