# как на гитхаб пейджес получить данные из формы

Tags: javascript, github-pages

Как сделать на гитхаб пейджес получение из формы данных(форма на другой странице), допустим есть такой код, как это реализовать

```
<html>
<head>
<title>тест для входа</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="страница назначения" method="post" id="pas">
Ваш пароль:<br>
<input type="text" size="40" required>
<input type="submit" vaule="отправить">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: с методом post никак. Можно попробовать поменять на `get` и на новой странице доставать из строки запроса гет параметры.

Comment: а можно по конкретнее про достать из строки запроса?

Comment: например так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/287469/186999

Comment: спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

ответ дан Grundy(за что ему спасибо)
с методом post никак. Можно попробовать поменять на get и на новой странице доставать из строки запроса гет параметры.
например так: ru.stackoverflow.com/q/287469/186999